# Google Sheets: Remove everything but the ending of a link in a specific column on paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to reduce the size of link names in a sheet automatically, and after hours of attempting to use different scripts, I'm having zero luck, and think it may not be possible.

I want to have it automatically format this column where we paste links to tickets.

**As an example, Column B:**

https://linktoticket.com/123456789

What I want to achieve:

There are multiple people reporting data and adding entries. To save them time, I want to have this portion automated so that when someone pastes the link to a ticket in Column B, it removes all sections of the text field leaving just the numbers (the end of the ticket) to be cleaner.

Is this possible? Everything I've attempted has fallen short.

I've tried =CONCATENATE, REGEXEXTRACT(), and SUBSTITUTE.

This script is what I thought would achieve this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  
  if (range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    var newValue = e.value;
    var pattern = /\/(\d+)$/;
    var ticketNumber = newValue.match(pattern);
    
    if (ticketNumber != null) {
      ticketNumber = ticketNumber[1];
      var textFieldRange = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 3);
      textFieldRange.setValue(ticketNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like for it to listen to any changes in Column B being made, and if someone pastes a URL into Column B it checks for the ticket number at the end of the URL, and keeps only the digits at the end of the URL and sets it as the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try on an adjacent column the following formula

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D10, "(.*\/)","")+0
```

For a range try this one

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(D10:D12, "(.*\/)","")))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

Comment: I tried and unfortunately couldn't get it to execute what I was hoping for I did however, paste a script in my edit that does work similarly, but isn't executing or making changes to the URL on the sheet.